# How to validate, that an array contains a specific value?

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

Say a model has an array property of integers, like

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I want to make another field required, if the array contains a specific value:

```
'record.status.*' => new EnumRule(Status::class),
'record.status_other' => ['required_if:record.status', 'contains the value 1'],
```

Any idea how to create a rule for `'contains the value 1'`?

Comment: ``status.status_other`` should be required if ``record.status == 1`` that's what you mean?

Comment: @OMiShah no, record.status is an array, that may contain 1.

Comment: did you try with `Rule::requiredIf()` where you can pass a closure?